# Deserialize a list of objects java

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I have some problems when trying to deserialize a list of objects. I have searialized a list of objects into a .dat file. If I want to retrieve the data from that file later, when I try to deserialize that list I don't get the desired result. Here is the code.

Serialization:

```
MyFile mf = new MyFile("2012-12-18.dat");
             mf.Open();
             FileOutputStream fos = mf.GetOS();

             Iterator<Element> currencies = cube.select("Rate").iterator();
             ISerializare[] lista = new ISerializare[31];
             int i=0;
             while (currencies.hasNext()){
                    MyCurrency newCurrency=new MyCurrency();
                    Element newElement=currencies.next();
                    newCurrency.setSymbol(newElement.attr("currency"));
                    newCurrency.setValue(Double.parseDouble(newElement.text()));
                    lista[i] = newCurrency;
                    System.out.println(newCurrency.toString());
                    i++;
             }
             DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);

             for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
                 lista[j].ObjectSerialization(dos);
             }
             dos.close();
public class MyFile {

    File fisier;
    String name;

    public MyFile(String n){
        name = n;
    }

    public void Open(){
        fisier = new File(name);
    }

    public FileOutputStream GetOS() throws IOException{
        return new FileOutputStream(fisier);
    }

    public FileInputStream GetIS() throws IOException{
        return new FileInputStream(fisier);
    }
}



MyFile mf = new MyFile("2012-12-18.dat");
     mf.Open();    
     FileInputStream fis = mf.GetIS();
     DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);

     for(ISerialization element:list){
         element.ObjectDeserialization(dis);
         System.out.println(element.toString());
```

and here is MyCurency class:

```
    public class MyCurrency implements ISerialization
{
private String symbol;
private double value;
public String getSymbol() {
    return symbol;
}
public void setSymbol(String symbol) {
    this.symbol = symbol;
}
public double getValue() {
    return value;
}
public void setValue(double value) {
    this.value = value;
}
public String toString(){
    return symbol +" = "+value + " RON";
}
@Override
public void ObjectSerialization(DataOutputStream dos) throws IOException {
    dos.writeDouble(value);
}
@Override
public void ObjectDeserialization(DataInputStream dis) throws IOException {
    value = dis.readDouble();
}
```

Can you please tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you please tell me what is wrong?

There are lots of things which could be wrong. Since you are not specific I will have to use my imagination.

The method names don't follow Java Coding Conventions which doesn't make them easy to read.  Using a code formatter would help.

The most obvious issue is that you only write the `value` field which means the `symbol` will be `null` after you deserialize it.

Also

```
System.out.println(element.toString());
```

is the same as

```
System.out.println(element);
```

And

```
return symbol +" = "+value + " RON";
```

has no formatting for value so it might print YEN 100.0 or USD 100.0 when it should be YEN 100 and USD 100.00 and it's not obvious why you have " RON" at the end.

---

If it helps at all, this is how I would write it

```
Collection<Element> currencies = cube.select("Rate");

// write out
File mf = new File("2012-12-18.dat");
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(
        new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(mf)));
dos.writeInt(currencies.size()); // so you know how many to read.
for (Element currency : currencies) {
    MyMoney newCurrency = new MyMoney(currency);
    newCurrency.writeTo(dos);
}
dos.close();

// read in
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(
        new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(mf)));
int count = dis.readInt();
List<MyMoney> myMoneys = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    myMoneys.add(new MyMoney(dis));
dis.close();

public class MyMoney {
    private final String symbol; // this is a currency
    private final BigDecimal value;

    public MyMoney(Element element) {
        this(element.attr("currency"), new BigDecimal(element.text()));
    }

    public MyMoney(DataInputStream dis) throws IOException {
        symbol = dis.readUTF();
        value = new BigDecimal(dis.readUTF());
    }

    public MyMoney(String symbol, BigDecimal value) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getSymbol() {
        return symbol;
    }

    public BigDecimal getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return symbol + " " + value;
    }

    public void writeTo(DataOutputStream dos) throws IOException {
        dos.writeUTF(symbol);
        dos.writeUTF(value.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I've changed a little bit the code now. Maybe this time is easier to read. Thank you

Comment: I don't get any errors, so I really don't know what's wrong. I think that something went wrong when trying to deserialize that list of objects.

Comment: @Cristina - he means ... "what did it output, and how is that different to what you were expecting?"

Comment: It doesn't output anything. It should output something like : AED 0.9223 RON and many other currencies

Comment: I suspect your `list` empty so the loop is not looping.  As I stated, you won't see the symbol as you are neither writing nor reading it.

Comment: I've also give you the serialization code and MyFile class. I really don't know how to solve this.

Comment: The problem is that I would re-write everything, but it wouldn't teach you much.  I suggest you trying to figure out what your code is doing as the solutions are fairly simple once you understand the difference between what your code does and what it should do.

Comment: I can't figure what this is doing. That's why I need your help. I really don't understand what is wrong because I used the same piece of code on other list of objects and it works fine.

Comment: I've tried it all day and also googled a lot to solve this problem. I do some reasearch before posting a question.

Comment: I have re-written it the way I would write it and added it to my answer.